# Can I blindly trust WolframAlpha?

Tags: integration, wolfram-alpha

Recently, my friend gave me the following indefinite integral to evaluate : $$\int \frac{\sin^2 x }{\sin x +\cos x} \mathrm dx$$

I searched it on WolframAlpha, just to be sure, that whether it has an elementary primitive or not. It turn out to be not a elementary one.

[image]

Then I asked him, that why did he gave it to me, if it wasn't supposed to be a question for High-schoolers?
His reply surprised me! He had solved it. It goes as follows -

\begin{align}\int \frac{\sin^2 x }{\sin x +\cos x}\mathrm dx &=\int \frac 12 \left(  \frac{\sin^2 x +\color{blue}{\cos^2 x}}{\sin x +\cos x} + \frac{\sin^2 x -\color{blue}{\cos^2 x}}{\sin x +\cos x} \right)\mathrm dx \\
&=\frac 12 \int \frac{1}{\sin x +\cos x}\mathrm dx +\frac 12 \int (\sin x -\cos x)\mathrm dx\\
\end{align}

Now the first part can be solved using $\sin x +\cos x = \sqrt 2 \cos \left( x -\dfrac {\pi}4 \right)$ and $\int \sec x \mathrm dx = \ln (\sec x+ \tan x )$. Second part is trivial.

Did I get something wrong, or Wolfy is the wrong one here?

Comment: Apparently , Wolfram alpha presents a complex antiderivate. It is possibly the problem of "knowing too much"

Comment: WA misses possible simplifications from time to time, and when it does the result may be really ugly.

Comment: I think it used the change of variable $t = \tan(x/2)$ that works for all algebraic fractions in $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Comment: For what it's worth, sometimes you gotta massage the answer: https://imgur.com/a/aBWbb

Comment: Don't blindly trust anyone or anything, in particular not Wolfie A.

Comment: By default, WA considers complex variables, which can make the answers look uselessly contrived. But as a rule of thumb, WA is always right and I disagree with other negative opinions here. IMO, the factor $(-1)^{3/4}$ is a sign that several branches can be considered.

Comment: While I don't want to crack through the algebra of it, I would not be surprised if Wolfie's answer does not simplify to your friends answer.  Wolfie frequently gives answers that are correct but perhaps not very nice.

Comment: So is the answer given by WA convertible into elementary one? Sorry, I don't know about inverse hyperbolic functions.

Comment: differentiate the given solution and simplify it, i think, nothing is wrong

Comment: @JaideepKhare: you can escape the complex constants. The hyperbolic function has an expression in terms of more usual functions (logarithm).

Comment: Wait, WA understands $LaTeX$?!? Why was I not told sooner!

Comment: you must type TeXForm[%] to convert in $\LaTeX$

Comment: Content. But please pardon me for being too judgmental. I remove my vote. Now it is locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha did a perfect job, as usual.

Looking just below the answer, there is a plot clearly showing that the complex version is considered.

And looking a little more below, alternate forms are given, the first of which doesn't have the complex constants.

If you worry about the hyperbolic function, you have to know that WA's answer and yours are equivalent, and the reference to a well-known function is probably a good idea.